# how to create filter excel for multiple columns using vba

Tags: excel, vba, loops, multiple-columns

I have a worksheet with 7 columns (B:H). In each column the 3rd row (B3,C3 etc.) is a an input cell. The rows below contain a database and I want this database to be filtered based on the input cells in the third row with one push of a button. This is my code so far, but it doesn't work. I'd be grateful if one could help.

```
Sub HideRows()

  Dim rCheck As Range
  Dim rHide As Range
  Dim rCell As Range
  Dim rCol As Range

    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Set rCheck = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B4:H230")

        For Each rCol In rCheck.Columns
            For Each rCell In rCol.Cells

                If Not InStr(1, rCell, ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(3, rCol), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                If Not rHide Is Nothing Then Set rHide = Union(rHide, rCell) Else Set rHide = rCell
            End If

            Next rCell
        Next rCol

    If Not rHide Is Nothing Then rHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Look at `Range.AutoFilter` =)

Comment: or [Range.AdvancedFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.advancedfilter)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! However, I want my database filters a bit less specific. I have one column with names who are part of a project team and these names are separated with a comma. If I type 'Frank' in the filter box, i want all projects with Frank as one of the team members to show. I guess this is not possible with the two filters you suggested?

Comment: Have you really investigated? It perfectly possible =)